# Send float var via UDP with C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, udp

Hello as you can see I new here (and in C++ and Qt).

Please help me, I want to send some commands from my application to X-Plane (flight simulator) via UDP. In short I need to send message like this:

```
DREF0XXXXsim/joystick/yoke_roll_ratio
```

where XXXX are four bytes of float value.
Problem is, when I send a float value like 0 or 0.5, in these values some bytes are 0 (?) and c++ thinks that this is the end of message.

I use `memcpy` to change float value into 4 bytes (char), but in case that some of them are `0` my message end.

Other values (e.g. 0.1, 0.2 etc.) are ok. I found that I can change zeros into e.g. 1 but in that case when I send 0.5 value I received 0.50392 (when I send 0.4 I received 0.4000000).

I use Qt library and this function to send data:

```
socket->writeDatagram(const char * data, qint64 size, const QHostAddress & address, quint16 port)
```

The question is - how to send zero byte or float value like 0.5 or 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use memcpy to change float value into 4 bytes (char), but in case that some of them are 0 my message end.

No, you don't. `memcpy` *copies memory*, in your case the 4 Byte that make up a float. You don't have to do that to just use that memory in places like `writeDatagram`:

```
writeDatagram(const char * data, qint64 size, const QHostAddress & address, quint16 port)
```

is the [signature](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram), so you might just call

```
writeDatagram(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(myfloat_pointer), 4, ....)
```

UDP and Qt really don't care what's inside the data, so your problem with 0 bytes comes from something else -- I suspect your `memcpy` mechanism; do you, per chance, use `strlen` or something to determine how much memory you want to copy?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
reinterpret_cast<const char*>(myfloat_pointer)
```

solved the problem. I changed my code and now it is working:

```
char strToSend[509] = "DREF0";
char c[4];
char *cp = &c[0];
cp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pitchValue);
memcpy(&strToSend[5], &cp[0], 4);
std::string dref = "sim/joystick/yoke_pitch_ratio";
memcpy(&strToSend[9], dref.data(), dref.size());
socket->writeDatagram(&strToSend[0], 509, host, 49000);
```

I'm not really sure that this is a good/beautiful code but it works - X-Plane receive correct data.